# Special SQL condition query for finding first two records and the last one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a dataset like:

```
 student_id     date     project_id
 1              1/1/18   15
 1              1/1/18   17
 1              2/2/18   16 
 1              3/3/18   15 
 1              3/3/18   12 
 2              2/3/18   3
 2              4/3/18   4
 2              5/3/18   6 
 2              5/3/18   4
```

I want to find the student id with the first two project they did and the last they did with date,

```
student_id    project_id1st    date1st     project_id2nd      date2nd projectlast    datelast
1             15               1/1/18      17                 1/1/18  12               3/3/18
2             3                2/3/18      4                  4/3/18  4                5/3/18
```

Firstly I want to solve it in pandas, but got some bad result. Then I tried to solve it in SQL.

```
WITH abc AS (
  SELECT student_id, project_id, date, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) rn
  FROM table 
)
SELECT student_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN abc.project_id END) as firstid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN abc.project_id END) as secondsid,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN date END) as first,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN date END) as second
FROM abc
GROUP BY 1;
```

I got the good result but somehow it messed up with the order of dataset by using `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example, in terms of student 1, the project_id 17 having the value of 1 in rownumber, project_id 15 will become the second starting date.

Comment: I have filling that you need `distinct on(...)` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: What is your expected order when you have the same date? If you want `date` and then `project_id` you have to tell this in the `order by` clause.

Comment: @S-Man the same order in the raw dataset, but when I use `row_number()`, it messed up

Comment: Your problem is that you have no column which indicates the right order. In the `row_number` window frame you give an order by date. But when there are many rows in the frame the result is completely random. You have to tell the database what to with rows in the same frame. Would you like to take the `project_id`? Or to you need a timestamp instead of the date? There is no such indicator as "raw order". This can never be ensured. So you cannot get the one right answer.

Comment: select min(t.test), max(t.test), t.bez, min(x.test) from test t
left join (
 SELECT test, bez,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bez ORDER BY bez) rn
 FROM test) x on x.bez = t.bez and x.rn = 2
group by t.bez

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have no column which indicates the right order. In the `row_number` window frame you give an `order by date`. But when there are many rows in the frame the result is completely random.

You have to tell the database what to do with rows in the same frame. Would you like to take the `project_id`? There is no such indicator as "raw order".

For example

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

never gives a dedicated order (e.g. the order the datasets were inserted). The result set could be ordered completely random. Same is for any frame window you define.

So you will need a way (a column or an algorithm) that ensures the order you expect.

---

If you would take the `ORDER BY date, project_id` then (for example) the frame for `3/3/18` will be ordered with `project_id` `12, 15` which is not your "raw order". If you would order it `DESC` your `1/1/18` frame is ordered wrong because the first id would be `17`. So `project_id` is not a good order criterion. But there's no other possibility for ordering. That's because you'll need another column.

To get your "raw order" an auto increment ID column (type `serial` - or in case of **Postgres 10** and higher [`GENERATED AS IDENTITY`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/) - would help).

---

When you have a certain order (e.g. an insert ID column) then this could be your query:

```
WITH abc AS (
    SELECT insert_id, student_id, project_id, date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY insert_id) rn_asc,        -- A
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY insert_id DESC) rn_desc   -- B
    FROM projects
)
SELECT 
    student_id,
    MAX(project_id) FILTER (WHERE rn_asc = 1),
    MAX(date) FILTER (WHERE rn_asc = 1),
    MAX(project_id) FILTER (WHERE rn_asc = 2),
    MAX(date) FILTER (WHERE rn_asc = 2),
    MAX(project_id) FILTER (WHERE rn_desc = 1),
    MAX(date) FILTER (WHERE rn_desc = 1)
FROM abc
GROUP BY student_id
```

A: Ordering the student frames by ID ascending and giving the row numbers `1` and `2` which help to filter the first two rows.

B: Ordering the same descending to get the last row (which gets the `row number == 1` in this case)

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=237eef158034240783a1871dda0cb965)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it with a simple join, for example:

```
select min(date), max(date), t.bez, min(x.date) from table t
left join (
    SELECT date, student_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM table
    group by date, student_id) x on x.student_id = t.student_id and x.rn = 2
group by t.student_id
```

You can simply group by date and student_id at your ROW_Number() so you dont get the same date twice

Answer (score 0):

Use order by with 2 columns project_id and date

[[Demo]](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=30a71b9e074aa2f8c41c441b2f46c992)

```
WITH abc AS (
  SELECT student_id, project_id, date, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date,project_id) rn
  FROM table 
)
SELECT student_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN abc.project_id END) as firstid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN abc.project_id END) as secondsid,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN date END) as first,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN date END) as second
FROM abc
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: This will not work as you see in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=efd25aa12a8e36a3700f05fcc3b00c8e For me it shows the rows (student: 1, first: 12, second 15) which is not the expected result.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: @S-Man, I've changed the order by option and it worked

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c5e86554cf3ead07f2cdc8bba7edc9e4 As you can see, your row_number() is not working as expected. Because you are ordering by project_id, the order is wrong at the end. The TO expects the project_id 12 as last, but because your order the 15 is last.

Answer (score -1):

Please try casting to integer.

> WITH abc AS ( SELECT student_id, project_id, date,
>
> **CAST**(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) **AS INT**) rn FROM table )

Comment: That makes no sense. `row_number` is already a bigint. Changing that to an integer won't make any difference